# In A and in B, structure

Tags: sentence-structure

I've made this sentence, but it doesn't seem good. Can you explain to me why it's not good and how I should fix it?

> In a society where their achievement or performance is more valued and welcomed and in a society where those who make great efforts can become or have what they have wanted to the extent they had hoped, people would more likely to do their best in their lives.

Comment: Your sentence is far too long and complicated for the reader to take in. It needs to be trimmed severely or split up.

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence mixes verb tenses, is wordy, is awkwardly structured, and has at least one grammatical error:

- The present tense provides a simple way to express a statement of fact (e.g.,  "people *are* likely" or "what they *want*") without requiring conditional modifiers (e.g., "would be likely" or "what they have wanted").
- "Achievement and performance" is wordy; "valued and welcomed" is wordy. In both cases, the terms are  close in meaning, and the additional term doesn't provide much additional information. The phrase "those who make great efforts can become or have what they have wanted to the extent they had hoped" is particularly wordy.
- It can sound awkward to begin a sentence with a long clause describing the circumstances and leave the important consequence to the end. Sometimes the sentence is more effective if it states the result immediately and then describes the conditions.
- "Would more likely to do" is ungrammatical.

More succinctly, you might say, **"People are more likely to work hard in a society where their achievements are valued and success is attainable."** This revision has the advantage of brevity and parallelism: "NOUN is/are ADJECTIVE and NOUN is/are ADJECTIVE". And although I could be wrong, it seems like the revision conveys just about the same meaning as the original sentence.